# PHP DomDocument appendChild() on a non object

Tags: php, parent-child, domdocument

I have a PHP class that is used to generate some HTML in the following way:

```
public $rName;
public $cName;
public $rMonth;

function __construct(){
    $this->report = new DOMDocument;
    $this->report->loadHTMLFile('template.php');
}

private function addComponent($tag, $content){
    $parent = $this->report->getElementById('content');
    $child = $this->report->createElement($tag, $content);
    $parent->appendChild($child);
}

function addSection($header){
    $this->addComponent('h2', $header);
}

function addSubHeader($subHeader){
    $this->addComponent('h3', $subHeader);
}

function addContent($content){
    $this->addComponent('p', $content);
}
```

which is being called like this:

```
$report = new Report;

$outputType = $_GET['outputType'];

$report->rName = 'rName';
$report->cName = $_GET['cName'];
$report->rMonth = $_GET['rMonth'];

$report->addSection('Section');
$report->addSubHeader('SubHeader');
$report->addContent('Content');
```

Using XAMPP on Windows, this code works absolutely fine. However on a centos environment I get the error:

> Call to a member function appendChild() on a non-object on line 16

Line 16 is:

```
$parent->appendChild($child);
```

The template.php file appears to be loading, and there is a div with the id of "content", however a gettype() on $parent shows it as NULL.

Pretty stumped at the moment. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In older versions of PHP, `getElementById` requires that an id attribute has been specified in a DTD.

Inserting `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the start of the HTML may be enough, in this case.

Comment: Yeah, it was the missing doctype that did it :)